# Contiki Makefiles creation

Tags: makefile, porting, contiki

I am creating a port for Contiki OS on LPC1347 micro-controller. I am aware that makefiles are required for making the port.
Since I am new to porting and creating makefiles, can you plese help me out with understanding and creating makefiles for simple application like LED blinking.

Comment: You are trying to build contiki for a micro-controller it doesn't currently support?

Comment: yes I am trying to build a port for LPC 1347 board which does not have support currently. Can you help me out with it?

Comment: Do you have the compiler/etc. toolchain you need for this to work? How does contiki expect to be cross-compiled for various toolchains? I would expect that you just need to point it at your desired toolchain. Have you read https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/README-BUILDING.md ?

Comment: I'm using gcc-arm toolchain. I have made changes in the respective makefile to use the particular compiler, but my question is: Is there any way i can understand makefiles line by line, what variables has what values etc.

Comment: That was not your question and if you want to understand what a makefile is doing you should read the [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) and possibly the [GNU Make Book](http://www.nostarch.com/gnumake) by John Graham-Cumming. (There are also any number of resources online, of varying quality, which discuss how makefiles work in general.)